# Can an LM317 voltage regulator be in series with an LM317 current limiter and work?

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-limiting

I'm building a power supply for a guitar pedal.

I'm using a voltage regulator that will set the voltage at 9 V, 12 V, 15 V or 18 V. Below is the schematic:

[image]

I also need to limit the current to 250 mA, so I was planning on connecting the voltage regulator in series with this current regulator circuit:

[image]

However, I'm unsure if this would work. I don't necessarily need to regulate the output current; I simply need to limit it.

Would placing a resistor of an appropriate value to the output of the voltage regulator be enough to limit the current?

Comment: Yes, one such example is in Figure 22 [of the On Semi LM317](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm317-d.pdf), although that circuit requires a bipolar supply so yours will vary

Comment: Pay attention to dropout voltages.  Your supply voltage will need to be several volts higher than your desired output voltage  for this to work.  I'm guessing at least 7 volts, based on the circuit that @PeteW references.

Comment: For lm317 as current limiter min drop voltage 3.25V. Not very effcient.

Comment: definitely not efficient by modern standards, even for linear. PS -- @DRC, 250mA for a guitar pedal? something with valves?

Comment: What they said. The current limit needs to be come before the ,vreg as you probably realise. A more efficient Ireg could be implemented with an opamp. And if desired a quad opamp a voltage ref and a MOSFET pass transistor could be more efficient again - if that's important to you. Maybe only 2 watts total losses in the two stages.

Comment: it will work but these day there are more elegant solutions

Comment: Your dip switch allows 16 combinations. What happens if you accidentally enable all switches? A rotating selector would be simpler and safer for user errors.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: it works. You can limit the output current as \$ I_\text{out} \leq 1.25/R_1\$. If you want to limit the current to 250 mA \$ R_1 = 1.25/0.25=5\Omega\$. Just choose a resistor with a suitable power rating since the power dissipated by the resistor will be \$1.25^2/R_1=1.25^2/5 = 0.3125\text{ W}\$. However, the circuit is horribly inefficient and heats up if used in high-current applications (I toasted my hand several times). Each regulator requires a 3 V drop to work properly, meaning the supplied voltage must be greater than the output voltage by at least 6 V \$V_\text{out}\ +6 \leq V_\text{in}\$ and The wasted power is \$P_\text{loss} \approx I_\text{out}\times 6\$. You can check the following datasheets for more information:

LM317: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm317-d.pdf  
LM338: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm338.pdf